# HTML5 canvas does not display after creating another canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Hi i am new to posting on this forum but have used it for some answers before. I am doing a school project using HTML5,  CSS and JS to make some teaching lessons. I am using canvas to make some interactive tools,  my problem is this: i have several panels with different content on them, on one panel i am using canvas to show some images and information, i am now trying to create another canvas on a different panel but when i do this nothing is displays in the new canvas. When i remove the old canvas code the new canvas code will display but i assume there must be a way to have them both display, help would be much appreciated i really need to get this working for school. and sorry if this is hard to understand my english is still not that great. here is an example of the code if it helps.

```
<div class="panel">
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#myCanvas {
border: 1px solid #9C9898;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("h1Canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.moveTo(100, 150);
context.lineTo(450, 50);
context.lineWidth = 10;

// set line color
context.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
context.stroke();
};

</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="h1Canvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
</html>


</div>

<div class="panel">
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#myCanvas {
border: 1px solid #9C9898;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.moveTo(100, 150);
context.lineTo(450, 50);
context.lineWidth = 10;

// set line color
context.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
context.stroke();
};

</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
</div>
```

So everything in the first panel wont be displayed, but the second panel will. If i remove the canvas from the second panel then the first panel will be displayed.

```
<div class="panel">


<head>
<style>
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#myCanvas {
border: 1px solid #9C9898;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.moveTo(100, 150);
context.lineTo(450, 50);
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
context.stroke();
};

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas></div>
</body>


</div>


<div class="panel">

<head>
<style>
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#myCanvas {
border: 1px solid #9C9898;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var h1canvas = document.getElementById("h1Canvas");
var cntxt = h1canvas.getContext("2d");

cntxt.moveTo(100, 150);
cntxt.lineTo(450, 50);
cntxt.lineWidth = 10;
cntxt.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
cntxt.stroke();
};

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><canvas id="h1Canvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas></div>
</body>

</div>
```

the canveses are in different div's because each div is a different panel in a carousel so they need to be there and not put onto the same page.

Comment: why do you have another html document nested inside a div???? scary looking html

Comment: Avoid html blocks inside div... It creates horrible problems...

Comment: First of all, you really need to understand how to structure HTML before trying to understand what is wrong with your javascript. You shouldn't have multiple `body`nor multiple `head` tags. .... Damn, did I really post a recommendation on a 2012 questions...

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML structure is wrong, you need something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Here goes your css and js -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Here goes your html elements -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have made those changes but it has not made any difference, it seems to be a problem with canvas

Comment: @user1365234 - Canvas only works in later browsers... Are you using something like IE6...?

Comment: i am using the latest version of chrome, i know canvas works its just i have two instances of it and when one works the other does not.

Comment: @user1365234 We need to see the latest version of your code as there may still be structural problems with your new version.

Comment: all  ive done is remove the html tags by doing that the structure is right, even so they work fine independently so it is a problem with having two canvas elements i think rather than the html structure.

Comment: i dont understand this article exactly but i think it might be why my i am having problems(exert from http://html5.litten.com/using-multiple-html5-canvases-as-layers/): There is only one CanvasRenderingContext2D object per canvas, so calling the getContext() method with the 2d argument a second time must return the same object.
http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/#conformance-requirements

Answer (score 0):

Beside the poor structure you have two canvases both referred to by the same variable 'canvas' and two contexts referred to by the same variable 'context'. Hence you really only have one canvas and one context.

EDIT  OK here is your code tidied up plus I have changed the coordinates in your second canvas so that the two drawings do not overlap. You can change the coordinates as you wish.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#h1Canvas {
border: 1px solid #9C9898;
}
#myCanvas {
border: 1px solid #9C9898;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var hcanvas = document.getElementById("h1canvas");
var hcontext = hcanvas.getcontext("2d");

hcontext.moveTo(100, 150);
hcontext.lineTo(450, 50);
hcontext.lineWidth = 10;

// set line color
hcontext.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
hcontext.stroke();


var mcanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var mcontext = mcanvas.getContext("2d");

mcontext.moveTo(200, 250); //add 100 to coordinates so that two drawings do not lie on top of each other change as needed
mcontext.lineTo(550, 150);
mcontext.lineWidth = 10;

// set line color
mcontext.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
mcontext.stroke();
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="h1Canvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes i thought this might be the problem so i changed the variables to canvas1 and context1 and there doesnt seem to be any change either

Comment: Your changed code obviously still contained errors, probably structure errors. It would help you, as I suggested in an earlier comment, to publish any changed code to help spot the errors. You can do this by adding the code as an edit to your question.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to modify the code, ive learnt how to tidy up the code. but what you have done is put two instances of canvas on the same page, the <div class'"panel"> was in my code because they represent  two different slides or pages in a carousel, so i need to display the canvases on two seperate pages not one, i will try to put a better example of my code,thank you for for your time trying to help

Comment: @user1365234  you can apply css styles to a 'canvas' as you would a 'div' so mcanvas would be page 1 hcanvas page 2 etc. If you want to use 'div' then use

Comment: @user1365234 sorry my comment above got timed out Do not change width and height of a canvas using css as these stretch the canvas, top, left, visibility etc are OK. If you want to use 'div' surround each canvas with a div, ie  <div> <canvas>...</canvas> </div>

Comment: thanks for the suggestion its kind of late here, but ill try this in the morning

Comment: so using my example and using your suggestion of encasing the canvas with div would it look something like what ive changed it to

Comment: @user1365234 this is getting too long and it looks like you are still not clear on html page structure. Suggest you start a new question by copying the code I gave you, describing what you want to do and asking how to change the code to do it.